# Return false if the condition fails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know if there is a better way to write this piece of code in rails.

```
def self.get_user_id(name) 
    current_user_id = User.current.id
    user_id = User.where("name=?",name).id
    admin = check_admin(current_user_id)

    if (admin == TRUE || user_id == current_user_id)
       istrue = user_id
    else
       istrue = FALSE
    end

    return istrue
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can improve. Valiable naming and return values. Better if you could return the specific `user_id` in you success case and `nil` when not. And also you don't need to explicitly say `return` at the end of the function. There are many coding standards for Ruby, best thing is to follow a good coding standard. So it will stick you to a certain way of declaring and defining things.

```
def self.get_user_id(name) 
    current_user_id = User.current.id
    user_id = User.where("name=?",name).id
    admin = check_admin(current_user_id)

    if (admin == TRUE || user_id == current_user_id)
       return user_id
    end

    nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic way of writing it is like:

```
def self.get_user(name) 
    current_user = User.current
    user = User.where("name = ?", name)

    return nil unless user == current_user
    return nil unless current_user.admin?
    user
end
```

Notice that I changed it to return the user object instead its id, this is better than passing id around at most time. Also, by convention, if you want to 'nothing' or 'invalid', it's better to return `nil` instead of `false`.

To adopt this piece of code, you also need to implement an instance method for `User` called `admin?` which does basically the same as your previous `check_admin` method. This makes your code more object-oriented, which is a more preferred style in Ruby.